# Partition of Natural numbers into 4 subsets!

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Partition $\Bbb N $ into four subsets.

Would this work? Also what is another possibility?

P$_1 $ = {x : x is prime and odd for some x $\in$ $\Bbb N $} = {3,5,7,11...}

P$_2 $ = {x : x is odd, but not prime for some x $\in$ $\Bbb N $} = {1,9,15,21,27...}

P$_3 $ = {x : x is even and evenly divisible by 10 for some x $\in$ $\Bbb N $} = {10,20,30,40...}

P$_4 $ = {x : x is even and not evenly divisible by 10 for some x $\in$ $\Bbb N $} = {2,4,6,8,12...}

Comment: $2$ is a prime, $1$ is not.

Comment: then what ? what's your constrain ? use congruences by 4 and you're done

Comment: There is no set constrain @marmouset ok, good to know

Comment: @GoodDeeds oops, my bad

Comment: yes, it works. It is as good as the solutions proposed by the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $1$ is not a prime and $2$ is! Hence, your sets don't quite work. Why not try something like:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P_{1}&=\{4k\mid k\in\mathbb{N}\}\\
P_{2}&=\{4k+1\mid k\in\mathbb{N}\}\\
P_{3}&=\{4k+2\mid k\in\mathbb{N}\}\\
P_{4}&=\{4k+3\mid k\in\mathbb{N}\}
\end{aligned}.
$$

Or, if the sets don't have to be infinite:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P_{1}&=\{1\}\\
P_{2}&=\{2\}\\
P_{3}&=\{3\}\\
P_{4}&=\{k\mid k\geq 4\}\cap\mathbb{N}
\end{aligned}.
$$

Comment: Good idea! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How about?
 1. Unity
 2. Even numbers that are not prime
 3. Odd numbers that are not prime
 4. Primes